# How to Set Several Owners for a Google Drive Folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to give equal Ownership to my Google Drive folder to several persons and it is not possible in the GDrive. Is there any way I can fix that.

Answer (score -2):

**Sharing settings is your master control for a particular file or folder.**
You can give Is owner permission to several person.
You can pick a visibility option for each item in your Google Drive that you want to share and an access level for each person or group of people that you’ve shared something with.

In addition to choosing something’s visibility option and access level, you can also do the following:

1.Grab the link of a file or folder to share with someone.

2.See who has access Add collaborators (editors, commenters, or viewers) by name or mailing list 
3.Remove collaborators or change someone’s access level

4.Transfer ownership of your file to someone else

Comment: "You can give Is owner permission to several persons", can you?